# Calculating the Euclidean distance between 2 points on a circle in D-dimensional space

Tags: python, pytorch, geometry

It's fairly straightforward to calculate a direct Euclidean distance between 2 points:

```
import torch
p1 = torch.tensor([1.0, 3.5])
p2 = torch.tensor([5.0, 9.2])

dis = torch.sum(torch.square(p1-p2))
dis
>>> tensor(48.4900)
```

However, how can I calculate the distance between 2 points on circle without going through the circle? That it, the distance on the circle's perimeter, in D-dimensional space.

Clearly, in 2D a circle is just a circle:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circle_points(r, n):
    circles = []
    for r, n in zip(r, n):
        t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, n, endpoint=False)
        x = r * np.cos(t)
        y = r * np.sin(t)
        circles.append(np.c_[x, y])
    return circles

r = [2]
n = [20]
circles = circle_points(r, n)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for circle in circles:
    ax.scatter(circle[:, 0], circle[:, 1])
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
point_1 = circles[0][0]
point_2 = circles[0][11]
print('point_1: ', point_1, 'point_2: ', point_2)
>>> point_1:  [2. 0.] point_2:  [-1.90211303 -0.61803399]
```

While in 3D it will be a sphere, 4D hypersphere, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `center` ben the center of your circle.

Then you can compute the angle between the two center-to-point vectors with the dot product formula, which relates the dot product with the cosine of the angle and the norm of the vectors (look for the geometric definition of the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product))

```
normalize = lambda vect: vect/vect.norm()
v1 = normalize(point_1 - center)
v2 = normalize(point_2 - center)
angle = torch.arccos(v1.dot(v2))
```

Then, the length of the arc is the radius of the circle times the angle, i.e

```
distance = angle*r
```

Comment: Simple and elegant, I like it! Can you just explain to me a few things? What's the purpose of the `norm()`? When you say the angle between the 2 points, are we talking from the center of the circle? What will the dot product give me?

Comment: Right, I'll update the answer to take the center into account. But yeah, you need the dot product between the center-to-point vectors ; it's just that I assumed the center to be (0,0) because it's what your image show. The `norm` is required because the formula works for unit vectors

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot : )